# How to disable modal mask background in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to disable the modal mask background in a certain components, but the API doesn't have such option. Does anyone have a solution for such case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple as this:

`<Modal mask={false} ... />`

...sometimes in antd, you have to look at the docs of the underlying rc-component to get the full API: https://github.com/react-component/dialog

Comment: `sometimes in antd, you have to look at the docs of the underlying rc-component`  So true.

Comment: @Kossel Many Thanks a lot for the help and good reference point!

Comment: @Kossel You can add `mask` to antd's documentation.